# How to determine if 2 .jar files are versions of "the same"?

Tags: java, jar, manifest.mf

At work I often receive Java webapp builds to deploy in production, which include all the dependencies in .jar files.

Some times, the delivered builds include duplicate jars with different versions, e.g. `log4j-1.2.3.jar` and `log4j-1.2.4.jar`, which breaks our deployment process.

I'm looking for a way to determine if two .jar files are different versions of the same thing. We are currently looking at the filenames, and if they differ by only digits then we consider them duplicates, but this approach doesn't work if the version is stripped from the filename.

It has occurred to me to look into the jar file contents, namely the `MANIFEST.MF` file for a property that is unique for that file.

Such a property must:

- be always present in any .jar's `MANIFEST.MF` file
- be common to all versions/builds of that .jar
- be unique to that .jar (e.g. must differ between log4j and log4j-api)

I checked the contents of a few manifest files and `Implementation-Title` or `Export-Package` seem like good candidates, but I'm unsure if they fit the criteria above.

What is the best way to determine if we have duplicate .jar files?

Comment: Can you compare files' hash?

Comment: hashing doesn't work because it will always differ, since I'm looking at different builds/versions of the same .jar.